# Importing a CSV loops to infinity in python

Tags: python, csv

I've accidentally created an infinite loop importing a CSV file using python. I don't see where the error is!

This is my code:

```
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') # Read the file
    next(csv_reader) # Skip the header row
    insert_sql = "INSERT INTO billing_info (InvoiceId, PayerAccountId) VALUES (%s, %s, )" # Insert SQL statement
    print("Importing Data")
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
        cursor.execute(insert_sql, row)
        mydb.commit()
```

The file is 4GB in size, so it's huge. However, in the print statement, I can tell that it starts over again at the top of the file.

Here is the entirety of the function:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='xxx',
                        host='xxxx',
                        database='aws_bill')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
    def read_csv_to_sql(source):
        try:
            with open(source) as csv_file: # Open the file
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') # Read the file
                next(csv_reader) # Skip the header row
                insert_sql = "INSERT INTO billing_info (InvoiceId, PayerAccountId) VALUES (%s, %s)" # Insert SQL statement
                print("Importing Data")
                for row in csv_reader:
                    print(row)
                    cursor.execute(insert_sql, row)
                    mydb.commit()
                print("Done importing data.")      
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception:", e)
            mydb.rollback()
        finally:
            mydb.close()
```

Why is are these statements creating an infinite loop?

Comment: What does the code look like where you call the `read_csv_to_sql()` function?  This may be part of the problem.

Comment: This is the code that calls the function: `choice = choose_action()

    # 1 Read to SQL
    if choice == "1":
        read_csv_to_sql(source)
        main()`. This is all of my code: https://pastebin.com/Ti3AB2ZQ

Thanks

Comment: Did you test it with a very small csv file - few lines only?

Comment: Not yet. Let me try that now.

Comment: I tried again on a smaller file. It did not loop infinitely! It worked correctly. Odd.  It definitely was looping over the same accounts over and over again on the original file.I let it ran all day before I realized it was doing that.

Why would the size of the file make a difference?